# Playwright + Firefox: How to disable download prompt and allows it to save by default?

Tags: node.js, download, prompt, webautomation, playwright

I'm using Playwright + Firefox to automate downloading of a CSV file from firebase. The download is initiated with a click on the button:

```
page.click(".table-download-button")
```

**Problem: There's a prompt to download the file (refer to image below). What can I do to accept the download without the prompt? I can't be clicking on the prompt since I am automating it. The same problem is not found in chromium, only firefox! (I have my reasons why firefox is needed)**

I have tried: Click on "Do this automatically for files like this from now on", however it doesn't work since once I restart the script the preference has been cleared

[image]

My code for the download portion:

```
const [ download ] = await Promise.all([
  page.waitForEvent('download'),
  page.click(".table-download-button")
]);
const path = await download.path();
```

Appreciate your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

You should use `expect_download` there:

```
async with page.expect_download() as download_info:
    await page.click("a")
path = await download.path()
```

Comment: Hi there, sorry, didn't mention that I'm on nodejs. However I have tried the equivalent in nodejs using Promise.all and page.waitForEvent('download'), which the same issue persists. Refer to the following link: https://playwright.dev/docs/downloads

Comment: Oh sorry. I came from a python question. I thought this was also python. The download event should handle that for you. Could you share a little bit more of your code using the event?

Comment: Have shared the code in my original post, it's the same as the documentation though. Just more info, this happens only with firefox, and not chrome.